# How to draw a solid color bitmap with a Text Centered?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

The code below should be creating a bitmap that is a 48x48 rectangle, of blue background color  and a Text (actually just a letter) centered horizontally and vertically of white color.

However nothing happens.

```
procedure MakeCustomIcon(AText: string; AWidth: Integer; AHeight: Integer; AColor: TAlphaColor; var ABlob: TBlob);
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  Rect: TRectF;
  InStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  InStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.SetSize(AWidth, AHeight);

    Bitmap.Canvas.Clear(AColor);

    Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
    Bitmap.Canvas.StrokeThickness := 1;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.White;
    Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;

    Rect.Create(0, 0, AWidth, AHeight);
    Bitmap.Canvas.FillText(Rect, AText, true, 100, [TFillTextFlag.ftRightToLeft], TTextAlign.taCenter, TTextAlign.taCenter);

    Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;

    Bitmap.SaveToStream(InStream);

    InStream.Position := 0;

    ABlob.Clear;
    ABlob.LoadFromStream(InStream);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
    InStream.Free;
  end;
```

I  have tested the rest of my program to make sure the image (that Blob) is actually transporting and getting displayed, and it is doing so. The problem is fully contained on the way it is drawn the bitmap on the method above.

This TBlob is an array of byte.

I am looking to do rectangles like this below, to be used in TListView:

[image: this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prepared a project.

1-) Write Text on TImage

2-) Draw on TImage

3-) Effect to TImage

I Try on XE5

Samples:

```
procedure ReDraw(Image: TImage);
var
  MyRect: TRectF;
begin
  if Image.Bitmap.IsEmpty then Exit;

  MyRect := TRectF.Create(0, Ozellik.SeritTop, Image.Bitmap.Width, Ozellik.SeritBot);
  with Image.Bitmap.Canvas do
  begin
    BeginScene;
    if not Seffaf.IsChecked then
      Fill.Color := Ozellik.SeritRenk
    else
      Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Null;
    FillRect(MyRect, 0, 0, [], 1);
    Fill.Color := Ozellik.YaziRenk;
    if FontCombo.ItemIndex <> -1 then
      Font.Family := FontCombo.Items[FontCombo.ItemIndex];
    Font.Size := Ozellik.YaziBoyut;
    FillText(MyRect,FonYazi.Text.Trim,True,1,[],TTextAlign.taCenter,TTextAlign.taCenter);
    EndScene;
  end;
  Image.Repaint;
end;
```

http://www.dosya.tc/server32/vHsbaC/CapsYapMasa_st_.rar.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it is more helpful to show the code than a dubious link.

Comment: You're right, but the articles are a whole. How do I separate writings.

Answer (score 1):

All canvas drawings must be grouped into a **BeginScene/EndScene** block. Also, it is recommended to draw within a try-finally block.

So, instead of

```
Bitmap.Canvas.Clear(AColor);
...
Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
...
Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
```

you should do:

```
Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
try
  Bitmap.Canvas.Clear(AColor);
  ...
finally
  Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

-- Regards